# Entity Framework load related objects without available navigation property (DTO)?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have some objects in EF using model first, most of the objects are related:

```
Partial Public Class PersonLog
     Public Property Id As System.Guid
     Public Property ExternalEmailGuid As System.Guid
     Public Overridable Property Person As Person
End Class

Partial Public Class EmailIn
     Public Property Id As System.Guid
     Public Property PersonID As System.Guid
End Class

Partial Public Class EmailOut
     Public Property Id As System.Guid
     Public Property PersonID As System.Guid
End Class
```

Such that working with a Person object i can easily grab the associated PersonLogs

```
 _person.PersonLogs.OrderByDescending(Function(c) c.CreateDate).ToList()
```

However i need to grab the associated EmailIn or EmailOut objects associated with that PersonLog. No association was added between them and i'm not quite sure why.

Is there a way to load all of the associated EmailIn & EmailOut objects without iterating through each PersonLog item and performing a lookup? The relationship between PersonLog and EmailIn or EmailOut is 1:1

The approach I was considering was creating a new class that takes the current context and PersonLog as constructors and has public properties PersonLog, EmailIn and EmailOut, like this:

```
Public Class PersonLogDTO
Public Sub New(obj As PersonLog, cxt As DB.DBContainer)
    _obj = obj
    _cxt = cxt
End Sub
Public ReadOnly Property LeadLog As PersonLog
    Get
        Return _obj
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property EmailOut As EmailOut
    Get
        Return _cxt.EmailOut.Find(_obj.ExternalEmailGuid)
    End Get
End Property
```

Got to be a better way, right?

Comment: Where is there an association property pointing to `EmailIn`? Putting data access code in a DTO is a very bad idea, you should not do that and instead rework the associations.

Comment: The external email ID could point to an object of either email in or email out. I agree with you may just revwork the associations